# What could be stopping AJAX from returning?

Tags: javascript, ajax, browser

I'm trying to troubleshoot a problem on a client's machine for our website.  We're using an ajax call to get information on a page to select additional parameters.  Our callback function has a block of code for reading when the ajax coming back is an error or is correct.  For every other computer that we've tested this with, the ajax comes back.  However, for a particular client, we're seeing the ajax come back with the error message, meaning the response never got there successfully or that it's corrupted or broken.

Does anyone know how this would happen?  The client is using IE 8 and I've tested IE 8, IE 9, IE 10, and Chrome and all of those work on my computers.

EDIT: As of now, we don't have access to the system and the network that would be causing the error.  They are trying to see if they can accept everything from our domain and see if that fixes it, but right now, I can't put Fiddler on their computer.

Comment: What do you see in server logs from that machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen any amount of random behaviour caused by virus scanners and so-called network security products.  Try adding an exception for your site to any security software your client is running.

The other thing to do is to use Wireshark, Fiddler, etc. to see what's actually happening at the network level.